# Background service using alarm manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-pendingintent, android-intentservice

I have followed below example code for implementing Periodic background service. Periodic task executes correctly If app on foreground on 1st time. If, I close application then Background service is not working.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services#using-with-alarmmanager-for-periodic-tasks

1) BroadcastReceiver service for Bootcomplete

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Launch the specified service when this message is received
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyTestService.class);
    context.startService(startServiceIntent);
}
}
```

2) BroadcastReceiver to start service

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;

// Triggered by the Alarm periodically (starts the service to run task)
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyTestService.class);
    i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
    context.startService(i);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome --------1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

3) IntenetService class: To execute my background task

```
public class MyTestService extends IntentService {


// Must create a default constructor
public MyTestService() {
    // Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
    super("test-service");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate(); // if you override onCreate(), make sure to call super().
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
}   
}
```

4) Service is started from activity as

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scheduleAlarm();
}

// Setup a recurring alarm every half hour
public void scheduleAlarm() {
    // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
    // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
            30000, pIntent);
}
}
```

5) Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="test.org.help">

<permission
    android:name="test.org.help.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="au.com.KPS.companion.ACCESS_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="test.org.help.permission.UA_DATA" />
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- This app has permission to register with GCM and receive message -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="test.org.help.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />

<application
    android:name="test.org.help.KPSApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_actionbar_logo"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon, android:logo">

    <!-- Activities -->
    <activity
        android:name="test.org.help.ui.activity.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.JanRainLoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.LinkListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="test.org.help.ui.activity.KPSFragmentActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="test.org.help.ui.activity.NotificationDialogActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label=""
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog.Notification"></activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="test.org.help.receivers.NotificationReceiver"
        tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="test.org.help.util.ACTION_SHOW_AGENDA" />
            <action android:name="test.org.help.util.ACTION_SNOOZE" />
            <action android:name="test.org.help.util.ACTION_DISMISS" />
            <action android:name="test.org.help.util.ACTION_SHOW_DIALOG" />

            <data android:scheme="KPS" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:pathPattern="au\.org\.KPS\.util/.*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
        tools:replace="android:theme,android:screenOrientation"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="test.org.help.ui.activity.AppTutorialActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="test.org.help.ui.activity.TermsAndConditionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_terms_and_conditions"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="test.org.help.ui.activity.WarningActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_Warning"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="test.org.help.ui.activity.DifferentUserWarningActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_Warning"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="test.org.help.ui.activity.AppWhatsNewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_Warning"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.UserUpgradeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_upgrade"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <!-- Facebook -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <!-- Services -->

    <receiver android:name="com.mobileapptracker.Tracker">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="test.org.help.service.DBUpdateService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="test.org.help.service.DBUpdateService"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="test.org.help.receivers.TimeChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <activity
        android:name="com.janrain.android.engage.ui.JRFragmentHostActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.janrain.android.engage.ui.JRFragmentHostActivity$Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />

    <!--Hockey app crash report-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.appIdentifier"
        android:value="@string/hockey_app_id" />

    <receiver android:name="test.org.help.syncmanager.Network.NetworkAvailability">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".android.action.broadcast" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".db.AndroidDatabaseManager"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" /><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <service
        android:name=".syncmanager.auto.MyTestService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".syncmanager.auto.MyAlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote"></receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".syncmanager.auto.BootBroadcastReceiver">

    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

If, implement above as sample project as separate then, background service is executing fine always. But If try to integrate with my existing code then not working...

**Edited: Found Solution**
It got resolved by adding full path android:name service in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name="test.org.help.syncmanager.auto.MyTestService"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: Explain how it is not working. Have you tried setting logs at different points to see if they get called? I wouldn't simply rely on seeing a Toast.

Comment: @shanmugapriyan did you get anything on this ?

Comment: Yes, I got the result. A mistake which I did was, I didn't give full class path on Manifest for service.

Comment: @Shanmugapriyan so is it working well now?

Comment: yep.. No  issue @Dika

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did You find any solution for the same?

Comment: yes @PravinsinghWaghela I got solution. as I specified on 1st comment here

Comment: @Shanmugapriyan Thanks, It seems I was also doing the same mistake, Thanks

Comment: @Shanmugapriyan you should reply to you question because the issue is resolved.

Comment: @tiagocarvalho92 what reply you are expecting?

Comment: Maybe something like : 
Hey, i end up finding what was the issue.
For services we need to have the full class name in the android manifest.
If you look at the question, without reading all the comments there is no answer